# Add custom DLL files in nuget package in new csproj

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, csproj

.nuspec file has section <files>, what are the alternatives for include localization resources for new csproj file? How to add custom DLL files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild multiple dll in a single NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976879/msbuild-multiple-dll-in-a-single-nuget-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the trick is to get your third party DLL added to the nupkg. This does it:

```
      <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ThirdParty">
      <HintPath>..\DLLs\ThirdParty.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(OutputPath)\ThirdParty.dll">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

If you install this package into an old-style csproj then a reference to `ThirdParty.dll` will be added.

However, if you install this package into a new-style csproj then a reference to `ThirdParty.dll` will *not* be added as a referece, irritatingly. Work in progress...