# How to include a local DLL reference in to a nuget package when calling msbuild pack?

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package

We have several projects that need to include a few static DLL. Therefore the project files include code like this:

```
   <ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="..\_Solutions\dependencies\abc123.dll" />
     <Reference Include="..\_Solutions\dependencies\def456.dll" />
     <Reference Include="System.Web" />
   </ItemGroup>
```

**Expected:**

We expected that the two dlls; `abc123.dll` and `def456.dll` would befound in the nupkg file.

**Actual:**

However, the nupkg doesn't include the `abc123.dll` nor the `def456.dll` files.

Answer (score 18):

One can always include custom content in the nuget-package. Like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(OutputPath)\ReferencedLib.dll">
    <Pack>true</Pack>
    <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

If you target multiple frameworks:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard1.6</TargetFrameworks>
  <TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage);IncludeReferencedProjectInPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="IncludeReferencedProjectInPackage" Condition="'$(IncludeBuildOutput)' != 'false'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="$(OutputPath)\ReferencedLib.dll" PackagePath="lib/$(TargetFramework)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to include a local DLL reference in to a nuget package when calling msbuild pack?

According [the issue on the GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891), this is currently not directly supported by NuGet.

The workaround I suggest is using the `.nuspec` file:

> NuGet allows you to disable the automatic generation of the resulting
>   .nuspec file and automatic collection of files by setting the
>    property in your project, along with a 
>   property that allows you to pass replacement tokens for parsing the
>   .nuspec file.

See [Martin`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976879/msbuild-multiple-dll-in-a-single-nuget-package/45004898) for details.