# Visual Studio Nuget Manager reports "unsupported" for the .NETStandard2.0 section of a custom Nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, package, nuget

We have a .NetStandard2.0 project which is meant to be packaged into a nuget following the technique explained here:

```
     https://stackoverflow.com/a/45004898/863651
```

with a nuspec file which looks like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
      <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45004898/863651   we had to resort to employing a seperate nuspec -->
      <!-- file because thats the canonical way to include more than one dlls into the resulting nuget   -->
      <metadata>
        <id>$id$</id>
        <tags>$tags$</tags>
        <owners>$owners$</owners>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <authors>$authors$</authors>
        <description>$description$</description>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <dependencies>
          <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">
          </group>
          <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
              <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
          </group>
        </dependencies>
        <frameworkAssemblies>
          <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5" />
          <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="Microsoft.CSharp" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5" />
        </frameworkAssemblies>
      </metadata>
      <files>
        <file src="bin\$config$\netstandard2.0\*.dll;bin\$config$\netstandard2.0\*.pdb;" target="lib\netstandard2.0\" />
      </files>
    </package>
```

As you can see there is a section targeting .NetStandard2.0. The nuget package is generated by our build server using the following msbuild scriptlet:

```
    <MSBuild Projects="C:\path\to\foo.csproj" Targets="Clean;foo;" Properties="SkipRestoringNugetPackages=true;Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU;" ToolsVersion="15.0" />
```

The resulting nuget package is getting pushed into a nuget server with the following specs:

```
    NuGet.Server v2.10.3.0
```

When reviewing the package through Visual Studio 2017 Nuget Package Manager of a .Net4.8 project the following is displayed on the sidebar:

[image: Nuget Package Manager]

Why does it say "Unsupported" for the .NetStandard2.0 section? Other packages don't display something like that and I can't find see any typos in the xml of the nuspec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found your issue could be related to the version of Nuget.Server package since you don't use nuget pack command. With same nuget package, when I use Nuget.server **2.10.3**, it displays unsupported, After I update the **Nuget.server** to 3.4.1, all works well now. Let me know if it helps:)

I made a package locally, when I try to consume it in VS all works well.
After I deploy same package to nuget server 2.10.3, it displays **unsupported**!

So if the issue occurs when you try to fetch the package from the server after you deploy to it. I think it's because the [Nuget.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/3.4.1) package you use is too old! Updating the Nuget.Server package can help resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for tuning in. As I said I'm using the msbuild task directly while the option "Generate Nuget Package on Build" is checked. I am using MSBuild from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe (version 15.9.21). Makes me wonder which nuget version MSBuild is using.

Comment: @XDS NuGet.Server v2.10.3.0 is quite old, try updating it to latest 3.4.1 to check if it makes any difference:)

Comment: @XDS Ok, I've just found your issue is related to the version of Nuget.Server package since you don't use nuget pack command. With same nuget package, when I use nuget.server 2.10.3, it displays unsupported, After I update the Nuget.server to 3.4.1, all works well now. Let me know if it helps:)

Comment: Please update your answer so that I can accept it. This will help people who come here figure out what's wrong without looking at the comments. Thank you again!

Comment: @LoLance - I have `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` and Nuget.server 3.4.1. Still shows unsupported version. Any idea what am I missing?